# SQL - Restricting JOINed Records by Date

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, sum

Using two tables in MSSQL:

One table, [CUSTOMER], containing information on donors.
- Relevent columns: [CustID], [Name]
One table, [DONATION], containing records for each donation given.
- Relevent columns: [CustID], [Amount], [Date]
The tables share a key, [CustID].

I want to aggregate the [Amounts] according to each [CustID]

```
SELECT DONATION.CUSTID
,PEOPLE.NAME
,SUM (DONATION.AMOUNT) as TOTAL_DONATION
FROM [dbo].[DONATION] INNER JOIN [dbo].[PEOPLE] ON DONATION.CUSTID = PEOPLE.CUSTID
GROUP BY
DONATION.CUSTID
,PEOPLE.NAME
HAVING SUM (DONATION.AMOUNT) > 100
```

**This query works fine**, even with adding the HAVING clause.

**When I want to restrict the dates of donations to aggregate (adding to the SELECT,GROUP BY, and HAVING clauses) however...**

```
SELECT DONATION.CUSTID
,PEOPLE.NAME,DONATION.DATE
,SUM (DONATION.AMOUNT) as TOTAL_DONATION
    FROM [dbo].[DONATION] INNER JOIN [dbo].[PEOPLE] ON DONATION.CUSTID = PEOPLE.CUSTID
    GROUP BY
DONATION.CUSTID
,PEOPLE.NAME
,DONATION.DATE
HAVING SUM (DONATION.AMOUNT) > 100
and DONATION.DATE > '1-1-2010'
```

The query **no longer returns aggregate sums** of each person's donations, but **returns individual donations** for each person, which meet the HAVING criteria.

How can I implement this date restriction? Is it how I'm joining or summing or....? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Move it to the **WHERE** clause

```
SELECT DONATION.CUSTID
      ,PEOPLE.NAME
      ,SUM (DONATION.AMOUNT) as TOTAL_DONATION
FROM [dbo].[DONATION]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[PEOPLE] ON DONATION.CUSTID = PEOPLE.CUSTID
WHERE DONATION.DATE > '1-1-2010'
GROUP BY
       DONATION.CUSTID
      ,PEOPLE.NAME
HAVING SUM (DONATION.AMOUNT) > 100
```

What this means:

```
- given the people who donated
- look only at data where donation date is in 2010 or later
- and within that data, show the people who donated a total of more than 100
```

Comment: This had the same effect as DONATION.DATE in the "HAVING". Only donations after a certain date are reported, but not properly aggregated as in the first query. So instead of looking for total donation amount over $100, it reports individual donations, resulting in multiple listings for some donors.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your first query like:

```
,SUM (CASE WHEN DONATION.DATE > '1-1-2010' THEN DONATION.AMOUNT END) 
     as TOTAL_DONATION
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't group by date unless you want one row per customer per date. 
How about doing it from the donation table and just looking up customer names?

select Donator=(select name from [people] where [people].custid=[donation].custid),
  custid,SUM(amount)
  from [donation]
  where [donation].date between '1/1/2011' and '1/15/2011'
  group by custid
  having SUM(amount)>100